# Left Ctrl releases when I hold it and press Z (QWERTZ keyboard)

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, hardware-failure

I have this issue on a new Katana GF66 12UCO, Windows 11 Home. Firstly, let me describe the issue as I have experienced it in practice. When editing text, I sometimes had a need for multiple undos, so I held the (**left**) Ctrl+Z key combination. Strangely, this did only one undo, and then started inputting a string of `z`s (lower case). Even more strangely, the **right** Ctrl, when pressed alongside Z, behaved normally (as desired, it rapidly performed many undos).

I investigated the behavior with [Keyboard Checker](https://keyboardchecker.com/) and found that, when I pressed the left Ctrl, and then the Z key, pressing the Z key *released the left Ctrl key*, which explained the `z` string. Also, this behavior is unique to that exact physical key. For example, on an American layout, my keyboard would start inputting `y`s because that's the character mapped to this physical key on that layout (tested).

I hope this is not a hardware issue. I am skeptical about using custom MSI software because, from my experience, some of their modded drivers actually cause incorrect functionality (for example, the pre-installed MSI drivers for Intel Iris Xe cause occasional graphical glitches, which is fixed by downloading the drivers via Intel Driver & Support Assistant). Thank you for your help.

**Edit 1.** I have not tested the keyboard behavior on Linux yet. I will do so as soon as I get my hands on something which can be turned into bootable media. If the issue persists there, then I am afraid MSI really did mess up the keyboard design.

**Edit 2.** I confirmed that the Z key does the same thing to the left Shift key (but not the right one!) when pressed down alongside it: it deactivates/releases it. The same goes for the Alt key.

Comment: Seems more and more like a bad keyboard design. Might be fixable using AutoHotKey.

Comment: @harrymc How could AutoHotKey fix the issue? I already remapped the right Ctrl to the left one with SharpKeys, sadly to no avail.

Comment: It would be much more complicated than that : The AHK script would need to be activated by left Ctrl/Shift/Alt doing Down+Up in a very short while, followed by Z in a reasonably short while, and will need to eat up these keys and send the appropriate key combination; but if the conditions are not met, then send the original keys. Complicated.